# REGEX for matching string plus first occurrence of the sub string

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation, regex-greedy

I am looking for a regex that solves the below problem. In below example, I am extracting the values for `VITMINC`

Test String

```
1. As VITMINC##1-0-1##1 days.As
2. amlodipine ##vitamin c##diclo##tabramycin eye drop##metformin##0-0-1##15 days. amlodipine ##1-0-1## 3 days.
3. Xylometazoline(P) Nasal drops##0-1-0##2 days.   Paracetamol 500mg tab##0.5-0-0-0##2 days. VITMINC##0.5-0-0##2 days.   Chlorpheniramine maleate 4mg tab##0-1-0##2 days.
4. VITMINC##0-0-0-1##2 days.
5. amlodipine##vitamin c##diclo##tabramycin eye drop##metformin##0-0-1##15 days.
```

Sample Output for the above strings

```
1. VITMINC##1-0-1##1 days
2. ##vitamin c##diclo##tabramycin eye drop##metformin##0-0-1##15 days
3. VITMINC##0.5-0-0##2 day
4. VITMINC##0-0-0-1##2 days
5. vitamin c##diclo##tabramycin eye drop##metformin##0-0-1##15 days
```

I am trying with below regex but not getting the expected output

```
VITMINC##.*##([0-9]+ [days]){1}?
VITMINC##.*##([0-9]+ [days])*?
VITMINC##.*##[0-9]+ days
VITMINC##.*##([0-9]+ days){1}?
```

Sorry, if my bad explanation. And thanks in Advance.

Comment: `VITMINC##(.*?)##[0-9]+ days`? [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DATAsn/1).

Comment: If you don't have single `#` between your double `##`, you can modify @WiktorStribiżew's regex to `VITMINC##([^#]*)##[0-9]+ days` so that it's more efficient. It uses `[^#]*` instead of `.*?` (which backtracks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you do not actually want to have `#` chars at the beginning of the matches (examples 2 and 5 are self-contradictory), you can use

```
(?i)VITA?MIN\s*C##.*?##[0-9]+ days
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XHxIBw/2).

**Details**

- `(?i)` - case insensitive modifier
- `VITA?MIN` - `VITAMIN` or `VITMIN`
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `C##` - a `C##` substring
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars,as few as possible
- `##` - a `##` substring
- `[0-9]+ days` - 1 or more digits, space, `days` substring.

Comment: Thank you for this. This solves my issue and for point 2 I just copy the half string by mistake # appears in the first place. Sorry about that. I will edit and fix it.